# When we hit SOAP request 1st time we are getting exception "java.sql.SQLException: Technical error occurred java.io.EOFException"

Tags: java, soap, soapui

When we hit SOAP request 1st time we are getting exception "java.sql.SQLException: Technical error occurred java.io.EOFException". However, when we hit same request 2nd time it comes up with response. Could you please help on this issue.

```
Error in logs:
    8318 Nov-25-2015 14:18:47,153 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers() trackingNum------649254585635
    8319 Nov-25-2015 14:18:47,164 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers() reqMsgId------23332333
    8320 Nov-25-2015 14:18:47,199 ProcedureCaller-call() {call  proc_chrd_sel_shpmts_by_trknbr(?)} mpags
    8321 ####<Nov 25, 2015 2:18:47 PM GMT> <Notice> <StdErr> <dje12008.ute.fedex.com> <revenueDataInquiry_devrdagws06> <Thread-23> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <14484611     27687> <BEA-000000> <java.io.EOFException>
    8322 ####<Nov 25, 2015 2:18:47 PM GMT> <Notice> <StdErr> <dje12008.ute.fedex.com> <revenueDataInquiry_devrdagws06> <Thread-23> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <14484611     27720> <BEA-000000> <at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2598)>
    8323 ####<Nov 25, 2015 2:18:47 PM GMT> <Info> <WorkManager> <dje12008.ute.fedex.com> <revenueDataInquiry_devrdagws06> <Thread-23> <<anonymous>> <> <> <144846     1127754> <BEA-002936> <maximum thread constraint weblogic.logging.LoggingOutputStream is reached>
    8324 ####<Nov 25, 2015 2:18:47 PM GMT> <Notice> <StdErr> <dje12008.ute.fedex.com> <revenueDataInquiry_devrdagws06> <Thread-23> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <14484611     27754> <BEA-000000> <at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1318)>
    8325 ####<Nov 25, 2015 2:18:47 PM GMT> <Notice> <StdErr> <dje12008.ute.fedex.com> <revenueDataInquiry_devrdagws06> <Thread-23> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <14484611     27755> <BEA-000000> <at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)>
    8326 ####<Nov 25, 2015 2:18:47 PM GMT> <Notice> <StdErr> <dje12008.ute.fedex.com> <revenueDataInquiry_devrdagws06> <Thread-23> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <14484611     27776> <BEA-000000> <at com.fedex.chronos.ags.jdbc.StatementExecute.run(StatementExecute.java:93)>
    8327 ####<Nov 25, 2015 2:18:47 PM GMT> <Notice> <StdErr> <dje12008.ute.fedex.com> <revenueDataInquiry_devrdagws06> <Thread-23> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <14484611     27827> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)>
    8328 Nov-25-2015 14:18:49,942   . - Technical error occurredjava.io.EOFException
    8329 java.sql.SQLException: Technical error occurredjava.io.EOFException
     at com.fedex.chronos.ags.jdbc.AGSCallableStatement.execute(AGSCallableStatement.java:489)
    8331         at com.fedex.chronos.ags.jdbc.AGSCallableStatement.executeQuery(AGSCallableStatement.java:514)
    8332         at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:137)
    8333         at com.fedex.chronos.rda.util.ProcedureCaller.getAGSResultSet(Unknown Source)
    8334         at com.fedex.chronos.rda.util.ProcedureCaller.getResulSet(Unknown Source)
    8335         at com.fedex.chronos.rda.util.ProcedureCaller.call(Unknown Source)
    8336         at com.fedex.chronos.rda.trackingnumber.ShpmtByTrackingNumberDAO.selShpmtByTrackingNumber(Unknown Source)
    8337         at com.fedex.chronos.rda.webservice.RevenueDataAccessServiceBD.lookupTrackingNumbers(Unknown Source)
    8338         at com.fedex.chronos.rda.webservice.RevenueDataAccessService.getTrackingNumberInfo(RevenueDataAccessService.java:36)
    8339         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    8340         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    8341         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    8342         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    8343         at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:117)
    8344         at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:91)
    8345         at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
    8346         at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
    8347         at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    8348         at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    8349         at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    8350         at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    8351         at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:420)
    8352         at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:687)
    8353         at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:266)
    8354         at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
    8355         at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:205)
    8356         at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:634)
    8357         at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    8358         at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    8359         at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:108)
    8360         at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:278)
    8361         at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:287)
    8362         at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:134)
    8363         at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
    8364         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    8365         at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    8366         at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    8367         at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    8368         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
    8369         at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    8370         at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    8371         at com.fedex.security.filters.RemoteHostFilter.doFilter(RemoteHostFilter.java:137)
    8372         at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    8373         at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367)
    8374         at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
    8375         at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    8376         at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    8377         at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    8378         at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
    8379         at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
    8380         at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
    8381         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)



    **when we run 2nd time we are getting proper response:**

    8386 Nov-25-2015 14:18:50,873 RevenueDataAccessService-getTrackingNumberInfo() after ....getTrackingNumberInfo---[]
    8387 Nov-25-2015 14:18:50,894 RevenueDataAccessService-getTrackingNumberInfo() revenueDataResponse--com.fedex.rda.revenuedatainquiry.Response@3a490af4
    8388 Nov-25-2015 14:35:29,270 RevenueDataAccessService-getTrackingNumberInfo() Inside the getTrackingNumberInfo....
    8389 Nov-25-2015 14:35:29,288 RevenueDataAccessService-getTrackingNumberInfo() revenueDataRecords....getTrackingNumberInfo---[]
    8390 Nov-25-2015 14:35:29,299 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers() inside lookupTrackingNumbers----
    8391 Nov-25-2015 14:35:29,320 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers() inside try block of lookupTrackingNumbers----
    8392 Nov-25-2015 14:35:29,326 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers() trackingNoLstSize--1
    8393 Nov-25-2015 14:35:29,353 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers() RDS_MAX_REQ value -- 25
    8394 Nov-25-2015 14:35:29,368 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers() After parsing string to Int, RDS_MAX_REQ value -- 25
    8395 Nov-25-2015 14:35:29,381 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers() recType--A
    8396 Nov-25-2015 14:35:29,401 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers() trackingNum------649254585635
    8397 Nov-25-2015 14:35:29,433 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers() reqMsgId------23332333
    8398 Nov-25-2015 14:35:29,454 ProcedureCaller-call() {call  proc_chrd_sel_shpmts_by_trknbr(?)} mpags
    8399 Nov-25-2015 14:35:31,925 CodeLookup-refresh() Codetable has expired. elapsedTime=596652147 cachedTime=1000000
    8400 Nov-25-2015 14:35:31,974 CodeLookup-refresh() Codetable has expired. elapsedTime=596652196 cachedTime=1000000
    8401 Nov-25-2015 14:35:32,006 ProcedureCaller-call() {call ? := rda_schema.proc_chrd_sel_code()} progmaster_rda
    8402 Nov-25-2015 14:36:00,862 CodeLookup-getCodeDesc() CODENOTFOUND: ctg:cust_bll_tp CodeId
    8403 Nov-25-2015 14:36:00,877 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers() ShpmtByTrackingNumberList------[ShpmtByTrackingNumberObj [databaseName=DLORA     ECI2_RDA, custAcctNbr=133074481, roleCustNm=AVTRADE LTD, chargeType=S, coCd=002, dvcNm=, setlmDt=10/20/2015, setlmNbr=543273551, lineOfBusCd=00002, abIn     vTypeCd=3, shpDt=11/02/2015, tendrDt=, revenueDt=11/02/2015, chrgEntryDt=11/03/2015, revItemId=4560010053110060, dbNm=R, errCrctnFlg=, billMediaTypeCd=1     , revItemTypeCd=400, onlnRevItemId=0015309010000303, curRevStageCd=3000, origLocId=BSH, destLocId=PGD, pymtPayorCd=1, cdoRqstDt=, cdoTypeCd=, setlmCurrC     d=GBP, setlmAmt=608.97, customsBillType=, pymtPayorCdDesc=Bill Shipper, chargeTypeDesc=Shipment Level, lineOfBusCdDesc=International, coCdDesc=FedEx Exp     ress, customsBillTypeDesc=, orsFlag=, trackingNumber=649254585635, billMediaTypeCdSecondDesc=PAPER, isGround=false, isNonTrans=false, isTrans=true, grnd     Shpmnt=false, expresShpmnt=true, otherShpmnt=false]]
    8404 Nov-25-2015 14:36:00,891 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers()  ShpmtByTrackingNumberList size is----1
    8405 Nov-25-2015 14:36:00,901 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers()  customsBillType----
    8406 Nov-25-2015 14:36:00,945 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers()  databaseName----DLORAECI2_RDA
    8407 Nov-25-2015 14:36:00,967 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers()  lob----00002
    8408 Nov-25-2015 14:36:00,992 RevenueDataAccessServiceBD-lookupTrackingNumbers()  revItemId----4560010053110060
    8409 Nov-25-2015 14:36:01,010 ProcedureCaller-call() {call ? := eci_schema.proc_chrd_sel_shpmt_revitem(?,?)} ECI2_RDA
    8410 Nov-25-2015 14:36:12,972 CodeLookup-getCodeDesc() CODENOTFOUND: ctg:pkgng_type_cd CodeId01
    8411 Nov-25-2015 14:36:12,997 CodeLookup-getCodeDesc() CODENOTFOUND: ctg:srt_key_cd CodeId
    8412 Nov-25-2015 14:36:13,070 CodeLookup-getCodeDesc() CODENOTFOUND: ctg:grd_svc_cd CodeId
```

Comment: How quickly are you getting the EOFexception? Could it be a timeout, or does it occur more or less immediately?

Comment: within 20-30 secs I am getting this exception and it's frequetly on server. When we hit 2nd time we are getting response.